# How to manage one giant TFS team project which has multiple projects in JIRA

Tags: git, tfs, jira-agile, repository-design

I could not find a solid solution where the situation and condition are very rare. We have a big project that has multiple projects (vs solutions) in TFS. They had some reasons that they decided to begin as one project where I can see the limitations pushes us to change this. There are some blogs that supports the idea of one giant TFS team project as below:

```
> http://nakedalm.com/working-within-a-single-team-project-with-team-foundation-server-2012/
> http://nakedalm.com/project-of-projects-with-team-foundation-server-2010/
> http://nakedalm.com/one-team-project/
```

Anyway, the major problem with single project is that we can have only one current sprint and one backlog that contains multiple project (vs solution) work items which is very stupid. Project team per each project (vs solution) is separated where their code base is common. Number of work items per sprint is very high and complicated for team members. Coupling is extremely high and the deployments are dangerous, side affects of any code block are unpredictable.

We decided to use Jira Agile instead of TFS for task management but we have to keep code base in TFS until all project teams have some maturity in Git knowledge.

We decided to use TFS4JIRA plugin for TFS<->Jira synchronization for this period. This synch is required to configure to match TFS project to JIRA project. The limitation is that we can only synch this big TFS project to one jira project in this configuration where we want to seperate each TFS sub project to a Jira project. This is the only way that we can manage sprints of each sub projects with different product owners and teams. Otherwise we will have only one backlog and one current sprint for this big project just like what we have in TFS.

TFS4Jira does not support such case. I am looking for a workaround to implement seperation of each project (vs solution) in a logical way.

Comment: You can easily have multiple current Sprints (one for each product) with a single Team Project.